# Show rows on first occurrence of each repeated value

Tags: mysql

Currently I am building a trading programme. I need the result to return when signal hits the next 0 or 1.

The signal column only has three values which are "0", "1", or "". 1 signifies buy signal and 0 signifies sell signal. "" just means to wait until a signal has been reached.

Sometimes there could be several 0 or 1 returned in a row but I only need to find the first row as that would be the timing to get in or out.

So my table looks like this.

```
id  coinType  signal        date
==========================================
1     A         0      2020-04-18 05:45:05
2     A                2020-04-18 05:46:05
3     A         1      2020-04-18 05:47:05
4     A                2020-04-18 05:48:05
5     A                2020-04-18 05:49:05
6     A         0      2020-04-18 05:50:05
7     A         1      2020-04-18 05:51:05
8     A         1      2020-04-18 05:52:05
9     A                2020-04-18 05:53:05
10    A         0      2020-04-18 05:54:05
```

I've tried the following code, but it doesn't seem to return the correct result.

```
SELECT * FROM table c WHERE `coinType`='A' and `signal` NOT IN ( SELECT `signal` FROM table WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM table WHERE `signal`!='' and id < c.id and `coinType` = c.`coinType`) ) ORDER BY id
```

The returned result will need to look like this

```
id   coinType   signal        date
==============================================
1      A          0       2020-04-18 05:45:05
3      A          1       2020-04-18 05:47:05
6      A          0       2020-04-18 05:50:05
7      A          1       2020-04-18 05:51:05
10     A          0       2020-04-18 05:54:05
```

Comment: Your sample data and results look identical, which make your question rather unclear.

Comment: please add data as text not as image see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: I've changed the format. Will this be okay now?

Comment: Ah thank you very much. I am fairly new to this site so I was unsure how to edit the codes. Thank you. I've included my mysql query too. Please can you check again if this post is ready to go :)

Comment: "I need the result to return when signal hits the next 0 or 1" can you please explain more about this in the question, I find it hard to understand what needs to be done even after looking at the required result...

Comment: I've added more details to the question. Thank you.

Comment: why id 8 is not a part of your expected result ? If there would be any blank signal between 7 and 8 id, in that case also will be ignore the next repeative signal ?

Comment: I only need to find the first instance of 1 or 0 when the previous is 0 or 1. So id 8 is not expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  MIN(id), 
  signal, 
  MIN(date) 
FROM 
  table 
WHERE 
  coinType = 'A'
GROUP BY
  signal
ORDER BY
  id DESC;
```

Will something like this do the trick?
You can also add `MIN(cointype)` to the select since you are filtering by coin type anyway or you can just add it to the `GROUP BY` part after coin type.

I hope I understood the question correctly now :) This will basically group by signal types for that coin and will give you the minimum id and date.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately it doesn't do the trick as it only returns three rows with signal 1, 0, "" each. As there are a lot of 0 and 1 and "", I think there will need to be a subquery to filter it out.